# Set QWidget to 100% size

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have a QTreeWidget inside QStackedWidget. How can I set that QTreeWidget to have 100% width and 100% height in QStackedWidget?

That QTreeWidget should have the same size as its QStackedWidget parent.

To have a responsive design.

Image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xJBm0Oc.jpg]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].  As it stands your question is very unclear -- the `QTreeWidget` should have the same size as its `QStackedWidget` parent.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I edited it.

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: I have a no code, I designed it in Qt Designer-

Comment: When describing a problem should be specific, nowhere in your question you mention that you are using Qt Designer, I recommend you put it, also do not indiscriminately use the tags, instead of placing width, height, etc. you must use the qt-designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt Designer, click the 3x3 box near the top center for each element in your tree.  It is called `Lay Out in a Grid`, and looks like the shortcut is probably `Ctrl-G`.  The other two layout options are `Lay Out in a Form Layout` and `Break Layout`.  It sounds like all of your widgets/containers currently are set on `Break Layout`.

[image: Lay Out in a Grid]

[image: Lay Out in a Form Layout]

[image: Break Layout]

This enables a `QGridLayout` for placing the sub-elements.

Without that, it is without a layout, and will only do absolute positioning.  For any container in Qt Designer, these three buttons act like a radio button group for the layout of the widget.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I edited a post, look at image, that layouts works, but I cannot set a layout (buttons are shadowed) if in stackedWidget page is only 1 item :/